# unable to get future value into Widget widget

Tags: flutter

i have a list view and i want to get a finishedDate from firebase for every listTile if condition is serving.
but i got an error future is not subtype of DateTime

what did i  do is:

```
 @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: widget.servineraProviders!.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, int currentIndex){
              DateTime? finishedDate;
              String state = widget.servineraProviders![currentIndex].providerState;
              if(state == "Serving")
                finishedDate = getFinishedDate(widget.servineraProviders![currentIndex].providerID);
                return Stack(
                    children: <Widget>[
                        Container(
                            width:double.infinity,
                            color: Colors.grey[50],
                            child: state == "Serving" ? Text(finishedDate.toString) : Text("provider is available")
                        )
                    ],
                );
            },
        );
    }
```

the finishedDate function is as follows

```
getFinishedDate(providerID)async {
    DateTime dt = await DatabaseService().getFinishedTimeOfService(providerID);
    return dt;
  }
```

then the getFinishedTiumeofService:

```
Future<DateTime> getFinishedTimeOfService(providerID) async {
    DateTime finishedDate = DateTime.now();
    try{
      await ordersCollection
        .where('orderStatus', isEqualTo: 'inprogress')
        .where('providerID', isEqualTo: providerID)
        .get()
        .then((querySnapshot){
          var doc = querySnapshot.docs[0].data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
            DateTime timeArrived =  doc['timeArrived'].toDate();//DateFormat("hh:mm").parse('${data[0].timeArrived}');
            List<String> parts = doc['estimatedTime'].split(':');
            int hours = 0, minutes = 0;
            if(parts.length > 2) hours = int.parse(parts[parts.length - 3]);
            if(parts.length > 1) minutes = int.parse(parts[parts.length -2]);
            Duration d = Duration(hours: hours, minutes: minutes);
            finishedDate = timeArrived.add(d);
        });
        return finishedDate;
    }catch(e){
      print(e.toString());
      return DateTime.now();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap your `Stack` widget with [Future Builder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html)

Answer (score 1):

wrap your widget with **Future Builder**

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap your Stack widget with **FutureBuilder** widget and pass the getFinishedDate method to future property of FutureBuilder

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: widget.servineraProviders!.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, int currentIndex){
        DateTime? finishedDate;
        String state = widget.servineraProviders![currentIndex].providerState;
        return FutureBuilder(
          future: getFinishedDate(widget.servineraProviders![currentIndex].providerID),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData && !snapshot.hasError) {
              return Stack(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                      width: double.infinity,
                      color: Colors.grey[50],
                      child: Text(snapshot.data.toString)
                  )
                ],
              );
            } else if (snapshot.hasError){
              print(snapshot.error.toString());
              return Text(snapshot.error.toString());
            } else {
              return CircularProgressIndicator();
            }
          }
        );
      },
    );
  }
```